# Convert/cast class to parent class type

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter mapbox_gl has a `LatLng` class which does not have a `toJson()` and `fromJson()` method. Therefore I've inherited this class to my own class and added the methods

```dart
class MyLatLng extends LatLng {
  MyLatLng(double latitude, double longitude) : super(latitude, longitude);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'latitude': latitude,
      'longitude': longitude,
    };
  }

  @override
  factory MyLatLng.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    double _latitude = double.parse(json['latitude']);
    double _longitude = double.parse(json['longitude']);

    return MyLatLng(_latitude, _longitude);
  }

}
```

I have a list `var latLngList = <MyLatLng>[];` How can I convert this list to a list with the type `<LatLng>[]`?

`LatLng` and `MyLatLng` are exactly the same only `MyLatLng` have the json methods implemented.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do any explicit conversion?  A `List<MyLatLng>` should already be substitutable for a `List<LatLng>`.

Comment: There would be a problem if you passed the `List<MyLatLng>` to a function that tried to add a `LatLng` to it.  If so, there are a number of ways to create a new `List` with the desired element type. `List<T>.from(other list)` would be a typical way.

Comment: but if Lating does not have `toJason` method, why do you make it `@override` in `MyLatLng` ?

Comment: @GNassro I realised that I shouldn't have done that

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks! Didn't knew about the .from method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution ^^

```
convert() {

   var data = [
     {"latitude":"23432324234","longitude":"21321324321"},
     {"latitude":"23432324234","longitude":"21321324321"},
     {"latitude":"23432324234","longitude":"21321324321"},
     {"latitude":"23432324234","longitude":"21321324321"},
    ];

    List<LatLng> latLng=MyLatLng.toArray(data);
 }
 -------
class MyLatLng extends LatLng {
   MyLatLng(double latitude, double longitude) : super(latitude, 
   longitude);

   ******

  static List<LatLng> toArray(dynamic data){
   return data.map<LatLng>((e)  {return MyLatLng.fromJson(e);}).toList();
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MyLatLng{ $latitude;$longitude }';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced something that maybe related,
It may not answer your question but it may help future readers.

I have a class `A` and another class `B`, where `B extends A`, then I have `List<A> L` where in runtime type it is `List<B>` because of some modelling things, and I need to add a new object of `A` called `O` to `L`, I couldn't add it using `.add(O)` because the list in runtime is not `List<A>`, so I added the new object `O` to the list like this: `L= [O, ...L];` because in this way im creating a new List.